# DVD Decrypter for linux

Tags: ubuntu, dvd, iso-image, ripping, decryption

I am looking for an alternative to DVD Decrypter that will run under Ubuntu.  Can anyone recommend software for this?  I do not need encoding/transcoding or anything fance like that, my only requirements are to save to an ISO image and de-CSS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[K9Copy](http://k9copy.sourceforge.net) is a good all-in-one solution with a friendly GUI. It can save DVDs to an ISO image, with or without shrinking for DVD-5 compatibility, and optionally transcode to other formats. You will need to activate the *multiverse* section of the repository in order to install it.